# Injecting annotation values from ResourceBundle

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

How can I read a value for an annotation from a `ResourceBundle`? 
Instead of using a fixed value for `@JsonProperty("myPropertyName")` I wonder if it is possible to do something like `@JsonProperty(env.getProperty("json.property.myproperty"))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. The [java language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.1) states

> It is a compile-time error if the return type of a method declared in
>   an annotation type is not one of the following: a primitive type,
>   String, Class, any parameterized invocation of Class, an enum type
>   (§8.9), an annotation type, or an array type (§10) whose element type
>   is one of the preceding types.

Spring processes your beans at runtime. The annotation needs to have its attribute values at compile time.